# Access a DriveApp Google Doc file using the DocumentApp Id of the Doc

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I use Apps Script to access a Drive File using only the URL of a Google Doc or the DocumentApp Id of said google doc?

```
function copyToGoogleDoc() 
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var thisFileId = ss.getId();
  var thisFile = DriveApp.getFileById(thisFileId);
  
  var parentFolder = thisFile.getParents().next();

  var newFolderName = ss.getRangeByName("newFolderName").getValue();
  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(newFolderName);
  var resumeName = ss.getRangeByName("resumeName").getValue();
  var resumeLink = ss.getRangeByName("resumeLink").getValue();

  var resumeDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(resumeLink);
  var resumeDocId = resumeDoc.getId();
  var resumeFile = DriveApp.getFileById(resumeDocId);
  resumeFile.makeCopy(resumeName, newFolder);

}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later.
```

The error pointing to this line:

```
var resumeFile = DriveApp.getFileById(resumeDocId);
```

I assume it's because a DocumentApp Id functions differently than a DriveApp Id?

In the beginning of the code, I was able to use a SpreadsheetApp Id to access the same Spreadsheet file within DriveApp.

I am the one running the script so there should be no issue with file permissions because it's my Drive and my Files.

How do I use Apps Script to access a Drive File using only the URL of a Google Doc or the DocumentApp Id of said google doc?

Comment: I think that in your script, when the value of `resumeLink` is a valid URL of Google Document, no error occurs at `DriveApp.getFileById(resumeDocId)`. So, from `The document is inaccessible. Please try again later.`, I'm worried that in your situation, the document of URL might be the invalid document that can be retrieved by `DriveApp.getFileById`. But, in this case, I think that such an error might occur at `DocumentApp.openByUrl(resumeLink)`. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? For example, can I confirm your sample Document for replicating your current issue?

Comment: For example, I'm worried that in your situation, the document of URL might be a DOCX file which is not Google Document. How about this? Or, how about confirming the mimeType of the file?

Comment: @Tanaike Hello Tanaike, for "For example, I'm worried that in your situation, the document of URL might be a DOCX file which is not Google Document. How about this? Or, how about confirming the mimeType of the file?" -- You are correct, it is a DOCX file. I didn't know that DOCX is invalid. Is there a way to copy resumeFile into newFolder if it's a DOCX using the URL?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer by guessing your value of `resumeLink`. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> You are correct, it is a DOCX file. I didn't know that DOCX is invalid. Is there a way to copy resumeFile into newFolder if it's a DOCX using the URL?

I understood that the file of `resumeLink` was a DOCX file. But, in this case, I guess that an error occurs at `var resumeDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(resumeLink);`.

And also, I guessed the URL of your DOCX file might be `https://docs.google.com/document/d/#################################/edit`. In this case, `#################################` is the file ID.

If my understanding of your current situation was correct, when you want to copy the DOCX file with the URL of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/#################################/edit`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var resumeDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(resumeLink);
var resumeDocId = resumeDoc.getId();
```

#### To:

```
var resumeDocId = resumeLink.split("/")[5];
```

- In this modification, the file ID is retrieved from the URL of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/#################################/edit` using `split`.

#### Note:

- If this modification was not useful and your URL of `resumeLink` is not like `https://docs.google.com/document/d/#################################/edit`, please provide the sample URL in your situation. By this, I would like to modify it.

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)